# How to get Firefox to correctly identify file download?

Tags: asp.net, firefox, download

The following asp.net code works fine on Chrome & IE, but Firefox shows the file as `MyDownload.zip.htm` and hence doesn't know what to do with it.

```
        //ASP.Net file download code
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyDownload.zip");
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/MyDownload.zip"));
        Response.Flush();
```

Any ideas how to get Firefox to recognise the attachment correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [MIME type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046) header:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
```